# Android Native application written in kotlin and React Native application

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio, kotlin

I have an android application written in Kotlin (Android studio) and the UI for the application written in React Native. My question is can these be linked together? If so how? Also, can you guys post some links I can go through.

P.S.: I have no idea about react native.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check **Native modules** in react native documentation with which you can connect your native code with react native js code .
https://reactnative.dev/docs/native-modules-android

https://reactnative.dev/docs/integration-with-existing-apps

Comment: But my whole application is already written in android studio. Do you mean that I will have to migrate the logic to class that extend ReactContextBaseJavaModule ?

Comment: or you can create a project in react native then create native modules in using java or kotlin in android studio